# Modifying Jenkins Description for a build

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins, jenkins-api

I would like to *remotely* change a Jenkins build description. I have my script all set and ready except for one tiny problem: Multiple line descriptions.

I am using the REST API and JSON in Jenkins to download the old description:

```
old_description=$(curl -s --user "$USER:$PASSWORD" --data-urlencode "tree=description" \
    "$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/$build_number/api/json")

old_description=${old_description#*:\"} #Remove JSON garbage
old_description=${old_description%\"\}} #Remove JSON garbage
```

The `curl command pulls out:

```
<font color=blue><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>
\r\n<font color=gold><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>
\r\n<font color=green><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font>
```

(*Note*: I added line breaks to make the above easier to read. This is pulled out as a single line).

The `\r\n` are separate lines, so I do this:

```
old_description=$(sed 's/\\r\\n/\
/g' <<<$old_description)
```

And that changes `$old_description` to:

```
font color=blue><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>
<font color=gold><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>
<font color=green><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font>
```

(*NOTE*: The new lines are part of the value. This is a three line description.)

My program (depending upon the command line parameters) can replace, append, or prepend a new description to the build:

```
if [ "$prepend_flag" -a -n "$old_description" ] #Prepend new description to old description
then
    new_description="$new_description<br/>
$old_description"
elif [ "$append_flag" -a -n "$old_description" ] #Append new description to old description
then
   new_description="$old_description<br/>
$new_description"
fi
```

Now, I'll redo the description:

```
if curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD   --data-urlencode "description=$new_description" \
    --data-urlencode "Submit=Submit" \
    "$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/$build_number/submitDescription"
then
    echo "Description successfully changed on Build #$build_number in Jenkins job $job_name"
else
    echo "WARNING: Description was not set. Manually change the descripiton of the build"
    echo "         for Build #$build_number in Jenkins job $job_name"
fi
```

If I am prepending or appending the new description the first time, I get this in Jenkins:

```
<font color=blue><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>
<font color=gold><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>
<font color=green><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>
<font color=red><b>My new description</b></font><br/>
```

Looks nice. The next time, it doesn't work. I get this:

```
<font color=blue><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>\n<font color=gold><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>\n<font color=green><b>At first you don't succeed. Try again</b></font><br/>\n<font color=red><b>My new description</b></font><br/>
<font color=blue><b>My new new description</b></font>
```

Note the `\n` showing up.

How can I fix this issue?

I've put the whole program in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DKN4nT61).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with this for a long while...

First, instead of doing this:

```
    new_description="$new_description<br/>
$old_description"
```

to append or prepend the line, I used `printf`:

```
new_description="$(printf "$new_description\r\n$old_description")"
```

By using `printf`, I put a `<CR><LF>` instead of just a `<LF>` in my description line separator. This way, I don't have a jumble of `<NL>` and `<CR><NL>` and I'm no longer dependent upon the operating system's definition of the line break.

The `sed` command took me a long, long time to figure out. I tried all sorts of things:

```
old_description=$(sed 's/\\r\\n/\r\n/g' <<<$old_description)
```

But, nothing seemed to work... I tried the `-E` flag which allows me to use the *extended* regular expressions, but it kept interpreting `\r\n` as replacing `\\r\\n` with `literal 'rn`.

After several hours of this, I finally tried double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks:

```
old_description=$(sed "s/\\r\\n/\r\n/g" <<<$old_description)
```

That worked! You normally use single quotation marks with sed to protect the regular expression from interpolation. However, the single quotes were also killing the interpolation of `\r\n` as `<CR><LF>`. Changing them with double quotes solved the problem.