# Changing Jenkins Build Name & Description through API in JAVA

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to change the Jenkins's build # and build description through REST API using Java. I could see that in the below URL, this guys has tried to change the build description using some curl code,

[Modifying Jenkins Description for a build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839258/modifying-jenkins-description-for-a-build)

I have no idea how he is achieving it through curl commands. Please help!

```
http://localhost:8080/job/<BUILD_NAME>/<BUILD_NUMBER>/api/
```

Answer (score 4):

```
curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD   --data-urlencode "description=$new_description" \
--data-urlencode "Submit=Submit" \
"$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/$build_number/submitDescription"
```

He is submitting webpage **form** data to `"$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/$build_number/submitDescription"`
Essentially he is emulating a user manually going to the build page, clicking "Edit Description" link, entering description and clicking "Submit" button. That's one way of doing it.

You can also do it from the Jenkins CLI.
Go to: `http://localhost:8080/cli/command/set-build-description` for help.
Once you have `jenkins-cli.jar` you can execute the following from the command line:

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ set-build-description <BUILD_NAME> <BUILD_NUMBER> YOUR-DESCRIPTION`

Comment: Hi Slav, I appreciate your effort on this. I basically wanted to do REST API service call to Jenkins as I mentioned http://localhost:8080/job/<JOB_NAME>/<BUILD_NUMBER>/api/  but through the CLI. Could you kindly re-consider ?

Comment: I can see that `/submitDescription` works if I replay the browser request using cookie auth, but in my script if I switch to BASIC auth then I get a 403

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do this in Perl (which I'm new to) and got the following to work for me:

```
sub ChangeJobDescription {
    my $url = 'http://jenkinurl/job/<job_name>/<job_number>/configSubmit';
    my $jsonData = '{"displayName" => "<new Build title>", "description" => "<new Build description>"}';
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    my $req = POST($url,
        Content_Type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            Content => [ 'Submit' => 'save', 'json' => $jsonData    ],
    );
    $req->authorization_basic('user', 'password');
    my $response = $ua->request($req);
    print $response->as_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make a POST call using the following URL and "Content-Type" header as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** in Payload.

URL: `http://<jenkins>:8058/job/MYJOB_NAME/BUILD_NUMBER/configSubmit`

[image: FORM VALUES]

Comment: What is the application you are showing in this screenshot?

Comment: This I answered my own question.  It's the [Chrome Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) addin.