# Editing builds in Jenkins through curl

Tags: php, jenkins, jenkins-api

I'm trying to make a simple change in my Jenkins build: edit a name of build's description to some other name. (Just for the sake of practice). I'm typing such a command in terminal:

```
curl -i -X POST -d ""Description":"Some_other_description_name"" \
  "https://My_Login:My_password@jenkins_url/job/job_name/job_number/"
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Thx in advance

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25428716/1579623

Comment: Using `""Description.. ` cannot work - either switch the outer double quotes do single ones or escape the inner ones.

Comment: Why not using `jenkins-cli.jar set-build-description` command? Wouldn't it be simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no api for doing this. But it is possible to update the description with submitting the **web** form for it:

```
curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD   --data-urlencode "description=$new_description" \
--data-urlencode "Submit=Submit" \
"$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/$build_number/submitDescription"
```

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428716/390177) of Slav.

If also want to change the build name, have a look for the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25432250/390177).