# How to set the build description via Jenkins REST API or Python?

Tags: python, jenkins

Is there any way (like Jenkins REST API or Python module) to set the existing jenkins build's build description ?

Many thanks :)

Comment: anyone can kindly help on it ?  ^^

Answer (score 14):

It seems this problem was resolved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427622/changing-jenkins-build-name-description-through-api-in-java), as follows:

```
curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD --data-urlencode "description=$new_description" \
    --data-urlencode "Submit=Submit" \
    "$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/$build_number/submitDescription"
```

Comment: My problem with this answer is that it ain't using Python. How one can solve it using the requests lib?

Comment: pleasae refer : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api