# How add description to Jenkins build by using Python

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests

I'm wondering how I can add a description to builds in Jenkins by using Python module "requests"

I tried to make a POST request. The status code is 200 but the description is not added.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://localhost:8080/job/IgorModuleA-trunk/301/submitDescription'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
creds = ('', '')
message = {'description': 'The build is failed'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(message), headers=headers, auth=creds)
```

Comment: when making `POST` with json, use `json=message` instead of `data=json.dumps(message)` and remove `Content-Type` header from `headers`

Comment: @IvanVinogradov I made a request <requests.post(url, json=message, auth=creds)> but it didn't help

Comment: I would try changing your POST request according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427622/changing-jenkins-build-name-description-through-api-in-java